# jQuery toggle if NOT this

Tags: jquery, this, slidetoggle, toggleclass

Forgive me if this is a newbie question:

I've got a menu set to open the next div to see more details, and if there is another div open already it will close it while it opens the new one. I cannot figure out how to close the div already open if you click on the header associated with that div. It just closes & reopens.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".heading").click(function(){
        if($(".content").is(":visible")){
            $(".less").removeClass("less");
            $(".content").slideUp(500);
        }
        $(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
        $(this).children(".more").toggleClass("less");
    });

});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you meant http://ardentpixels.com/clients/royalspa/services.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".heading").click(function(){
    // Cache stuff, so we don't have to keep generating jQuery objects
    var $this = $(this);
    var $thisContent = $this.next(".content");

    // Saves a boolean value to see if the clicked element's content is
    // currently visible
    var thisWasVisible = $thisContent.is(":visible");

    // Removes less class and slides up ALL visible content divs
    $(".less").removeClass("less");
    $(".content").slideUp(500);

    // Slide the clicked element's content div down and add less class,
    // but only if it's content was not originally visible. We don't want
    // to show it again if it was just hidden.
    if(!thisWasVisible){
        $thisContent.slideDown(500);
        $this.children(".more").addClass("less");
    }
});
```

Comment: It's a bit more confusing to me (probably because I'm still learning) but does what it needs to. Thanks!

Comment: @J-Max: I have added some comments to the code, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".heading").click(function(){
    if($(".content").is(":visible")){
        $(".less").removeClass("less");
        $(".content").slideUp(500);
    } else {
        $(this).next(".content").slideDown(500);
        $(this).children(".more").toggleClass("less");
    }
});

});
```

Probably the least invasive change to what you have, that should work.

Comment: This works for my original issue, but it breaks: if you click another header, it just closes everything & doesn't open the new div.